# in order to be iterable non-array objects must have a symbol.iterator () method react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**Problem:**

In my React native application, I have created redux-thunk action to access the user's current location. But when Running it give me this error called in order to be iterable non-array objects must have a symbol.iterator () method. This is how I have wrote my actions.

```
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';
export const GET_CURENT_POSITION = 'location/GET_CURENT_POSITION';
export const GET_CURENT_POSITION_SUCCESS =
  'location/GET_CURENT_POSITION_SUCCESS';
export const GET_CURENT_POSITION_FAILED = 'location/GET_CURENT_POSITION_FAILED';

const getCurrentPosition = (payload) => ({
  type: GET_CURENT_POSITION,
  payload,
});

const getCurrentPositionSuccess = (response) => ({
  type: GET_CURENT_POSITION_SUCCESS,
  response,
});

const getCurrentPositionFailed = (response) => ({
  type: GET_CURENT_POSITION_FAILED,
  response,
});

const getposition = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(getCurrentPosition({msg: 'startgetting'}));
    return Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        dispatch(getCurrentPositionSuccess(position));
      },
      (error) => {
        dispatch(getCurrentPositionFailed(error));
      },
      {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000},
    );
  };
};

export default {
  getposition: getposition,
};
```

This is how I have wrote reducers.

```
import {locationTypes as types} from '_store/actions';

const location = (
  state = {
    hasError: false,
    errorCode: '',
    error: '',
    location: '',
  },
  payload,
) => {
  switch (payload.type) {
    case types.GET_CURENT_POSITION:
      return {
        ...state,
        hasError: false,
        error: '',
        location: '',
      };
    case types.GET_CURENT_POSITION_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        hasError: false,
        location: payload,
      };
    case types.GET_CURENT_POSITION_FAILED:
      return {
        ...state,
        hasError: false,
        error: payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default location;
```

This is how I have dispatched the function in connect.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    createpatient: (patient) => dispatch(patientActions.createpatient(patient)),
    getposition: () => dispatch(locationActions.getposition()),
  };


};
```

I tried a lot to figure out what is wrong but I was unable to do so. Can someone help me with this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: try Object.assign(state,{hasError: false,location: payload}) in reducer instead of ...state